# Number formatting with php

Tags: php

Good night!
I'm trying to format a number with php that comes from "200" to "2.00". It may seem like a simple thing, but I'm not getting it ... Does anyone have any suggestions? Another example, "20000", should be "200.00".
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use PHPs [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number_format($number / 100, 2)` should return what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 100 then use `number_format`

*Warning: untested as I'm typing this from my phone*

```php
$num = 200;
echo number_format($num / 100, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

May the number will come from input box.
But input type number box doesn't support float type.
So you'd better use text type instead of number type.
It will be helpful.

```
$number = '200';
echo substr_replace($number, '.', -2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `number_format()` function formats a number with grouped thousands.

```
   $number = 200;
    echo number_format($number / 100, 2, '.', '');
```